# Omnet++ Energy (InetSimpleBattery) Plot Charts

Tags: omnet++, inet, energy

I'm done creating a project in omnet++ and trying to track energy usage in different nodes, but all the plots are frozen at one value (straight line) and does not change even if kept the simulation running for a long time.
I'm using InetSimpleBattery. Maybe I'm missing something. The is my ini values:

```
**.scalar-recording = true
**.vector-recording = true
**.batteryType = "InetSimpleBattery"
*.host[*].battery.nominal = 3800
*.host[*].battery.capacity = 3800 
*.host[*].battery.voltage = 3.3
*.host[*].battery.resolution =0.01s
*.host[*].battery.publishDelta = 0.01
*.host[*].battery.publishTime = 0.01s

**.battery.ConsumedVector = true 
**.radio.drawCoverage = true
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Why didn't anybody answer? I am recording my vectors and I can see that the vriable I'm using is changing, but my chart is a straight line. I think I've done everything as the manual, I really don't know where this is coming from.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, can you please post about it?